# How can I see normal print output created in Pycharm when running python code

Tags: python, printing, pycharm

Sometimes I want to just insert some print statements in my code, and see what gets printed out. Normally I just insert print() statements in my code, then run the tests and can see what gets printed out.

However, how can I see the results of print() when I do not have the tests yet? I know you can just insert a print statement in your file like this print('hi') and then right click and run the file and the result will show in your console. Or you can do python filename.py in your terminal.

However, my problem is, the print statements only prints like this when I have it globally (outside a class, for example the print('hello')). But when I have my print statement inside a class, nothing shows in my console.

For example:

```
print('hello')

def _generate_bookings(some stuff) -> None

    for event in events:
        print(event)
```

When I then try and see the result of the print call it only shows hello but not anything that is inside the class. Any ideas? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Comment: "But when I have my print statement inside a class, nothing shows in my console." The code shown here has syntax errors, and also does not show a class. It shows a **function**, which only runs if and when it is called.

Comment: That said: please try to locate problems yourself first before posting, by testing out possible causes. For example, do you see the same problem if you **don't** use Pycharm? (Also, what tests are you talking about?)

Comment: Finally: please read [ask] and ask questions **directly**. "Any ideas?" is [not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/). "Why doesn't the `print` statement appear to run?" is answerable, and is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a function but didn't call it.
You just described that the function takes something and does something, so can call it and pass something specific to it

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function

```
print('hello')

def _generate_bookings(list) -> None
    for event in events:
        print(event)

events = [event1, event2..]
_generate_bookings(events)
```